# Use multiSubnetFailover in sequelize and mssql packages

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, npm, sequelize.js

I have a backend application (Node.JS) that uses mssql (v7) and sequelize (v6) npm packages.

Since my production DB configuration is (and can be only) accessed by an AGL, hence I need to set `multisubnetfailover=true` in the DB connection string.

Although support for this existed in previous versions, I am unable to find the same in the current stable versions of the respective packages. (Here's a sample code for previous [sequelize](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/pull/362#issuecomment-307885255) and [mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/640#issue-313014675) version)

Is there a way to enable this in the newer version?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? In sequelize the option is set via `config.dialectOptions.multiSubnetFailover` which is [passed through](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/ebca506226dc97dd778ee055bdbaa371a7e2f71d/src/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js#L59) to Tedious's [constructor](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/ebca506226dc97dd778ee055bdbaa371a7e2f71d/src/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js#L64) as before and [checked by Tedious](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/98f8f48eeb5b51c00d20f0839c93e0b3bced04bc/src/connection.ts#L1536).

Comment: I had tried the same for sequelize by adding `dialectOptions { multiSubnetFailover : true }` in the config, but it did not work (Fails to connect to primary server [**note**: Its not a DB side issue]), but thank you @AlwaysLearning for your reply! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For sequelize (v6):

**Solution**:

```
...existing sequelize configuration
dialect: "mssql",
dialectOptions : {
   options: {
    multiSubnetFailover: true,
   }
}
...
```

**Approach**:
I was looking at the source code links sent by @AlwaysLearning in the comments above, and found that, if `multiSubnetFailover`'s value is not a [boolean](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/blob/98f8f48eeb5b51c00d20f0839c93e0b3bced04bc/src/connection.ts#L1537), an error is thrown.

I then updated my configuration to `dialectOptions.multiSubnetFailover : "1234"`, however I did not get the TypeError I was expecting. Then I looked at some more [code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/ebca506226dc97dd778ee055bdbaa371a7e2f71d/src/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js#L59) and found that `multiSubnetFailover` should be used inside `dialectOptions.options`.

#### For mssql (v7):

Got help from a [contributor](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql/issues/1366#issuecomment-1049339392).

```
...existing mssql configuration
options: {
      multiSubnetFailover: true,
    }
...
```

Cheers!